# Is there a way to generate percentages for multiple columns in a dataframe based on a condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Let's say I have a DataFrame such as this one bellow, filled with `True` and `False` values in most of the cells.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["A", "B", "A", "B"],[True, False, True, False], [False, True, True, True], [True, False, True, True]]).T

df.columns = ['category','col2','col3',"col4"]

df

  category   col2   col3   col4
0        A   True  False   True
1        B  False   True  False
2        A   True   True   True
3        B  False   True   True
```

I want to aggregate such values to estimate the amount of `True` in each column, by category:

```
  category col2 %True col3 %True col4 %True
0        A        1.0        0.5        1.0
1        B          0        1.0        0.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is problem in sample data boolean are objects, so error:

> DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Solution is convert columns to boolean and then aggregate `mean`:

```
df = df.set_index('category').astype(bool).groupby(level=0).mean().add_suffix(' %True')
print (df)
          col2 %True  col3 %True  col4 %True
category                                    
A                1.0         0.5         1.0
B                0.0         1.0         0.5
```

In real data should working:

```
df = df.groupby('category').mean().add_suffix(' %True')
```

Answer (score 0):

- you can used named aggregations of boolean columns
- forcing to float as col2 will cast back to boolean

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""  category   col2   col3   col4
0        A   True  False   True
1        B  False   True  False
2        A   True   True   True
3        B  False   True   True"""),sep="\s+",)

df.groupby("category").agg(
    **{
        f"{c} %True": (c, lambda d: d.sum() / len(d))
        for c in df.select_dtypes(include="bool").columns
    }
).astype(float).reset_index()
```